# Developing apps for the nokia n73 in Java?

Tags: java, symbian, nokia, n73

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to develop a key capturing application to analyse writing styles when using the SMS composer for the n73 using S60 2nd Edition, Feature Pack 3 SDK in Java? Originally, I thought that all Java applications would be sand-boxed making it difficult to call the native key capture functions available to symbian, but nobody has been able to clarify this for me. Does it hold any truth?

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This answer comes from my friend who knows a lot more about these things.

---

As this [J2ME FAQ](http://www.j2meforums.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_access_the_phone.27s_j2me.3F_.28memory.2C_phone_book.2C_inbox.2C_pictures....29_.3F) states,

> **Can I access the phone's j2me?**
>   **(memory, phone book, inbox,**
>   **pictures...) ?**
>   Generally no, this is
>   considered a security risk and most
>   manufacturers don't allow it. However,
>   a very small minority do, so check out
>   their developer's site.

So that'd be no. There's no direct way in MIDP libraries to access that data anyway. It may however be possible if you're lucky, but don't count on it. Also according to Sun this may be possible in MIDP3.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be talking as a user:
Opera Mini (a java-based application) is able to read and write user data (phone memory and memory card).

And I've also seen java-based applications that access hardware such as the phone's camera, and seen apps that call system APIs such as vibration or sound notifications.

However, I don't know how they implemented those things.

Note1: Nokia N73 is based on S60 3rd edition not 2nd edition.

Note2: In some cases (such as accessing user data), user authorization is required, unless the application is signed using a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started hacking about with my Nokia 6300 and J2ME.  This phone supports MIDP2 and J2ME, but unlike the N73 - it's Series 40, and doesn't use symbian for it's operating system.

One of the applications that I want to write, needs to make use of the phone book and as far as I'm aware this is possible using the PIM API (JSR-75).

AFAIK you can actually access SMS messages using C++ under Symbian.  Try [this link](http://www.forum.nokia.com/search/?eo=1&ea=1&k=SMS+access+symbian&submit=Search)